# Equivalence of the second moment of two random variables when their first moments and covariance with a third random variable are equal

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm trying to check under which conditions the standard deviation of two random variables is identical when I know some properties about other moments of these random variables. I suppose that their their first moments and their covariance with a third random variable are equal. In more detail, suppose $X $ and $Y$ and $H$ a three random variables. Suppose furthermore 
\begin{equation}
E(Y) = E(X),
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
Cov(X,H) = Cov(Y,H), 
\end{equation}
the moments are taken with respect to the same measure $P$. The random variable $H$ is not constructed such that it is Independent of either $X$ or $Y$. Finally, Suppose also that both random variables $X$ and $Y$ are always positive. Then, what conditions are needed so that

\begin{equation}
\sigma(X) = \sigma(Y)
\end{equation}

Comment: It's unclear what you're looking for. The independence counterexample should have resolved the question in my opinion. Are you trying to find cases where it's true?

Comment: Thank you very much , Matt. Yes, you're right independence resolves my question. You're also right in guessing that I'm looking for cases where the standard deviations are identical. I reformulate my question.

Comment: I don't think it will work for any $H$ unless it changes depending on $X$ and $Y$. An evil adversary could always construct a counterexample for any $H$, and I wouldn't be surprised if it they could always be chosen not to be independent.

Comment: Reformulating a question *after* some answer is posted is not a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What would happen if $H$ was chosen to be independent of both $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Great remark!  I change my question and assume that $X$ and $ Y$ are in general not independent of $ H$.

Comment: @fabian Better insist on the identical covariances being _nonzero_; else if we choose $H$ so that it is _uncorrelated_ with both $X$ and $Y$ (but _not independent_ of $X$ and $Y$), we have the same problem again.